# How we can create a table in excel as the below html?

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel, laravel-excel

Suppose I want to create a table with `php-excel` or `laravel-excel` that should has the following structure:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <th>Column A</th>
      <th>Column B</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>value 1</td>
        <td>
          <table>
              <thead>
                 <th>neste column 1</th>
                 <th>nest column 2</th>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                 <tr>
                    <td>nested value 1</td>
                    <td>nested value 2</td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody> 
          </table>
         </td>
       </tr>  
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I searched a lot and it seems that excel doesn't support nested table.
If it is possible, how we can do that?

Comment: No, MS Excel does not support nested tables; Excel is a simple spreadsheet.... you can manipulate it to some extend with merged cells, but you can't nest tables

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks. I will try with cell merging.